Oracle Pipe delimited column
I have a requirement to get the data from  table based on some condition.



Column1
Column2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



If a record is having ABC or DEF or JKL or XYZ in column1 and corresponding value in column2 is Y
Then the record must be picked

I also have a lot of requirements, but don't write them all down on Stackoverflow. Do you have any question?

This table design violates first normal form of data normalization which states that a column should only contain 1 value.  If it was properly designed, you wouldn't have to get tricky with queries and it would be much simpler.  That said, we have all had to deal with bad designs where we have no say so if you do have a say, don't remain quiet! I had to deal with a table once that had an alpha-numeric primary key where case mattered.  Insane!  I told the vendor that whoever came up with that should be fired!  lol  Stop the insanity!

Can you also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

With REGEXP_SUBSTR and CONNECT BY.
SELECT DISTINCT t.Column1, t.Column2
FROM test_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t.ID,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.Column1, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) AS col1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.Column2, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) AS col2
    FROM test_table t
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.Column1, '\|') + 1
      AND PRIOR t.ID = t.ID
      AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
) s ON t.ID = s.ID
WHERE s.col1 IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'JKL', 'XYZ') AND s.col2 = 'Y';

Output:



Column1
Column2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



fiddle

The OP's table does not have an id column.

Also, the OP tagged the question with Oracle10g and the REGEXP_COUNT function was not introduced until Oracle 11g.

One of the options could be using basic string functions ( SubStr() & InStr() )
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl AS 
Select 'ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ' "COLUMN1", 'Y|Y|N|N|Y' "COLUMN2" From Dual Union All
Select 'ABC|JKL|XYZ',   'Y|Y|N'  From Dual Union All
Select 'GHI|XYZ',   'Y|Y'  From Dual Union All
Select 'GHI|JKL',   'N|Y'  From Dual;




COLUMN1
COLUMN2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



Create a CTE to generate rows of extracted elements from both columns (see the elements' resultset at the end)
WITH      
  elements AS
    ( Select Distinct 
             COLUMN1, COLUMN2, LEVEL "ELEMENT_ID", 
             SubStr('|' || COLUMN1 || '|', 
                    Instr('|' || COLUMN1 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL) + 1, 
                    Instr('|' || COLUMN1 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL + 1) - 
                          Instr('|' || COLUMN1 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL) - 1 ) "COL1_ELEMENT", 
             SubStr('|' || COLUMN2 || '|', 
                    Instr('|' || COLUMN2 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL) + 1, 
                    Instr('|' || COLUMN2 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL + 1) - 
                          Instr('|' || COLUMN2 || '|', '|', 1, LEVEL) - 1 ) "COL2_ATTRIBUTE"
     From tbl
     Connect By LEVEL < Length(COLUMN1) - Length( Replace(COLUMN1, '|', '') ) + 2
   )

...  Select rows filtered with Where clause ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select   Distinct COLUMN1, COLUMN2
From     elements
Where    COL1_ELEMENT IN('ABC', 'DEF', 'JKL', 'XYZ') And COL2_ATTRIBUTE = 'Y'

R e s u l t :



COLUMN1
COLUMN2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



fiddle
... the elements cte check ...
Select   Distinct *
From     elements
Order By COLUMN1, ELEMENT_ID

CTE elements resultset:



COLUMN1
COLUMN2
ELEMENT_ID
COL1_ELEMENT
COL2_ATTRIBUTE




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y
1
ABC
Y


ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y
2
DEF
Y


ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y
3
GHI
N


ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y
4
JKL
N


ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y
5
XYZ
Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N
1
ABC
Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N
2
JKL
Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N
3
XYZ
N


GHI|JKL
N|Y
1
GHI
N


GHI|JKL
N|Y
2
JKL
Y


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y
1
GHI
Y


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y
2
XYZ
Y




XMLQuery can also do the job:
with data(Id, Column1, Column2) as (
    select 1, 'ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N|N|Y' union all
    select 2, 'ABC|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N' union all
    select 3, 'GHI|XYZ', 'Y|Y' union all
    select 4, 'GHI|JKL', 'N|Y'
)
select d.* from (
    select xmlquery(
    'distinct-values(for $i at $kidx in (ora:tokenize($X,"\|")), $j at $vidx in (ora:tokenize($Y,"\|")) where (
        ($kidx = $vidx) 
        and ($i = "ABC" or $i = "DEF" or $i = "JKL" or $i = "XYZ")
        and ($j = "Y")
        )
      return $ID)'
      passing id as "ID", Column1 as "X", Column2 as "Y"
      returning content
    ).getNumberVal() as ID
    from data
) x
join  data d on d.id = x.id
;


On Oracle 11g (and Oracle 21), this gives the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected fiddle The OP has tagged Oracle 10g - can this work on a version that old?

add "from dual" in the "with data" CTE… I always forget that most are not yet using 23ai…

You can write a function that finds which term in column1 matches your desired value and return the sub-string corresponding to the term in column2:
CREATE FUNCTION term_match(
  column1  TABLE_NAME.COLUMN1%TYPE,
  column2  TABLE_NAME.COLUMN2%TYPE,
  c1_match TABLE_NAME.COLUMN1%TYPE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_c1   VARCHAR2(200) := '|' || column1 || '|';
  v_c2   VARCHAR2(200) := '|' || column2 || '|';
  v_pos  PLS_INTEGER := INSTR(v_c1, '|' || c1_match || '|');
  v_term PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF v_pos < 1 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  v_term := LENGTH(SUBSTR(v_c1, 1, v_pos)) - COALESCE(LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(v_c1, 1, v_pos), '|')), 0);
  RETURN SUBSTR(v_c2, INSTR(v_c2, '|', 1, v_term) + 1, 1);
END;
/

Then use that to find the matching rows:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  term_match(column1, column2, 'ABC') = 'Y'
OR     term_match(column1, column2, 'DEF') = 'Y'
OR     term_match(column1, column2, 'JKL') = 'Y'
OR     term_match(column1, column2, 'XYZ') = 'Y';

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column1, Column2) AS
SELECT 'ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N|N|Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI|XYZ', 'Y|Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI|JKL', 'N|Y' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



COLUMN1
COLUMN2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



fiddle

If you want to split the table efficiently into rows and filter then you can use:
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT 1
             FROM   DUAL
             WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column1, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'JKL', 'XYZ')
             AND    REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column2, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) = 'Y'
             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column1, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column1, Column2) AS
SELECT 'ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N|N|Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC|JKL|XYZ', 'Y|Y|N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI|XYZ', 'Y|Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI|JKL', 'N|Y' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



COLUMN1
COLUMN2




ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N|N|Y


ABC|JKL|XYZ
Y|Y|N


GHI|XYZ
Y|Y


GHI|JKL
N|Y



fiddle
